# ubuntu nginx running twice -- cannot kill extra process

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, upstart

Fresh Ubuntu 12.04 instance running on Amazon EC2

got Nginx running with Passenger

added an upstart script

```
description "NGiNX starter"
start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
exec /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

the issue is that I have multiple nginx processing running (beyond worker threads)

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root       720  0.0  0.2  39624  1228 ?        Ss   03:23   0:00 nginx: master process /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx
www-data   722  0.0  0.3  40136  1884 ?        S    03:23   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   723  0.0  0.3  40136  1884 ?        S    03:23   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   724  0.0  0.3  40136  2388 ?        S    03:23   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   725  0.0  0.3  40136  1884 ?        S    03:23   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   726  0.0  0.3  40136  1884 ?        S    03:23   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2218  0.0  0.6  39620  3688 ?        Ss   03:45   0:00 /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

the way I read this is that process 720 has been started correctly and that processes 722,723,724,725,726 represent the worker threads configured in nginx.conf

what I don't get is what process 2218 is doing?
when I try

```
sudo kill 2218
```

I get the message

```
kill: No such process
```

when I then check with ps aux | grep nginx again the rogue process will be running under a new PID

thinking that there is something going on with the upstart script since if I move it out of /etc/init reboot the instance and then run the same ps aux | grep nginx nothing is running

if I then boot nginx manually then the rogue thread does not appear

I've used this same script on another server for over a year without issue
any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is `init` the parent of the "rogue thread"?

Comment: If you have `pstree` that will help you see the parents.

Comment: pstree showed that both nginx threads are initiated by init -- the set with worker processes is all 1 process -- the rogue thread is separate